# selling a Thomas Kinkade puzzle on eBay: can I legally photograph the puzzle?

Tags: united-states, copyright

Let's say I bought and put together a 1,000 piece [Thomas Kinkade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Kinkade) puzzle and that I wanted to now sell it on eBay.

All of his paintings are copyrighted so if it seems like I could be risking violating his (or his companies) copyright if posted a picture of the puzzle on eBay. But if I don't include a picture of the product I'm selling then the odds of it actually selling are slim to none.

I suppose it's only really an issue if the current holder of the Thomas Kinkade copyrights were to request I take the images down but just because someone doesn't warn you against doing something doesn't mean it's legal. Like even if the odds of you being caught are low, speeding is still illegal.

Maybe it'd fall under fair use if the picture I took were sufficiently low resolution?

Comment: Based on lighting, shot angle, etc. would your photo be a copyrighted derivative?  What about a photograph of the puzzle box that has a photo of the painting?